# save recorded voice permanently in a way such that it can be accessed only from that particular application

Tags: ios, avaudiorecorder

how to save  voice recorded using AVAudioRecorder permanently in a way such that this voice is available only to that particular application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL you pass to the `AVAudioRecorder initWithURL:settings:error:` method is a file URL to a location in your app's sandbox. This is where the audio file will be saved. Since this is in your app's sandbox, no other app has access to it (at least on a non-jailbroken device).

Keep in mind though that if the user deletes your app, any recording you save in the app's sandbox will be deleted along with the app.

Comment: can you please suggest some code to record audio for a particular duration say 5sec